# Can't reduce System sounds volume?

Tags: windows-10, audio, system-sounds

Whenever I reduce the `System sounds` volume in the `Sound mixer options`, then I close the window after having done so, it immediately reverts back to 100%.

How can I permanently reduce it?

[image]

Comment: Well known bug. No solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a work-around using NirCmd.

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

`nircmd.exe changesysvolume -5000`

I can't test this right now but it might be worth a try.